# {fmt} Replace only one positional argument in string several positional arguments

Tags: c++, fmt

I would like to know if {fmt} library allows to amend only one positional argument in string containing several positional arguments ?

Here is my test which doesn't work and {fmt} documentation shows no solution

```
std::string text = "{name} is {nb} years old and lives in {city}";
try
{
    text = fmt::format(text, fmt::arg("name", "John"));
}
catch (const fmt::format_error::exception &e)
{
    std::cout << e.what() << std::endl;
}
```

I would like to get `John is {nb} years old and lives in {city}`, is it possible ?

Comment: What if the value of `name` were `{city}`, literally? Then the result would be `{city} is {nb} years old and lives in {city}`. When you feed this to `fmt` later where `nb` and `city` are filled in, you get "garbage" (aka unpredictable results), and that is the reason why incomplete replacements are not allowed.

Comment: See @j6t's comment. You could always pass `{name}` and `{city}` for `name` and `city` in case they are not available.

Answer (score 1):

No. Referring to a non-existent argument, positional or not, is an error.